# You will need to have me, What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> You will need to have me,
>
> If you wish to come inside.
>
> For this place is Very exclusive,
>
> With you my secret must reside.
>
> But if you manage to get me,
>
> Access will be yours.
>
> You may now enter the building,
>
> And unlock any doors.

What am I?

Comment: I did not voted close / downvote but would like to let you know the reason.  If you look at it, there are too many answers that fit, e.g. a key, access card, password (from answer), fingerprint unlock, security, anyone lives / works in the building, etc etc.  You can improve your riddle by narrowing the possible answers.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're

> A Key

You will need to have me,
If you wish to come inside.

> Use a key to unlock a door and enter somewhere

For this place is Very exclusive

> Each key opens a specific door

With you my secret must reside

> You must keep it with yourself

But if you manage to get me
Access will be yours.
You may now enter the building,
And unlock any doors.

> Literally unlock any doors

Comment: I had originally though this, but your descriptions to "very exclusive" and "unlock any doors" are contradictory.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense

Answer (score 4):

I think you are

> an access card

You will need to have me,
If you wish to come inside.

> Can't gain entry without an access card

For this place is Very exclusive,

> Only people with an access card can enter.

With you my secret must reside.

> Don't share your access card with anyone!

But if you manage to get me,
Access will be yours.
You may now enter the building,
And unlock any doors.

> The access card will gain you access to the building and the other doors in the building.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're a

> Password

You will need to have me,
If you wish to come inside.

> Use a password to log in

For this place is Very exclusive,

> Only users with passwords can get in. Also, one user has one password. Account specific information is very exclusive indeed.

With you my secret must reside.

> Don't publicize your password.

But if you manage to get me,
Access will be yours.
You may now enter the building,
And unlock any doors.

> Again, you can log in with a password. Building and doors are metaphorical here.